# Angular dob problem when click on set date

Tags: javascript, angular, date, datepicker

I have a problem when I try to select a date in the date picker, any date I select resets to today's date and I don't know why. Can someone please help me with this issue?

This is the stackblitz, what should I change for the date to be the date I want to be displayed? Thanks a lot

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbj5vz

Regards

Comment: It only resets back when you click the button because you're initialising the date again, what's the issue? what do you want it to do?

Comment: You should take value from date picker but your creating new date object with current date and time (now) and setting value in form.

Comment: Hello, I want to insert a date into the date picker and to have that value that I added not the date from today, I hope its clear

Comment: You are already able to insert a date to the datepicker. The "today issue" happens only when you click the button. What do you want the button click to do? Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8bjak9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html you'll see in the console that your date is changing correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you are initializing the date after pressing the button.

Edit - try this instead please:

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.builder.group({
      dob: new Date()
    });
  }

  formatFormDate(date: Date) {
    return formatDate(date, this.dateFormat, this.language);
  }

  setDate() {
    let newDate = this.form.get('dob').value;
    this.form.patchValue({ dob: this.formatFormDate(newDate) });
  }
```

Comment: Hello DaveWuzHere, thanks a lot for your response. When I add this code I get errors like Object is possibly 'null', and my app can't compile successfully. Do you have any idea why, or do I have to set some statements about newDate above or something? Thanks a lot

Comment: @tirbushonn23 Can you try the newly edited code when you get a chance?